# Transparent area in button and pass touch to below button

Tags: android, button, touch, overlay

**Description:**

I have 2 button and my one button overlap half the other button.my button have ireegular shapes. Due to which some are in my button have transparent area.the area whic overlap other button.

**My problem**

When i click on transparent area of button.then touch should be trigered on button below it.I am unable to transfer touch to below button.and vice versa

**Explation by picture**

[image]
[image]

explaintion:

rectangle with black color is button and  rectangle with light green color is also button
and  transparent area of light green rectangle button overlap black.

**My Accomplishment**
i have triggered that touched area is transparent area of button or coloured

```
    Bitmap TheBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.menu);
    int eventPadTouch2 = event.getAction();
    int iXi = (int) event.getX();
    int iYi = (int) event.getY();
    switch (eventPadTouch2) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if (iXi>=0 & iYi>=0 & iXi<TheBitmap.getWidth() & iYi<TheBitmap.getHeight()) {                 
            if (TheBitmap.getPixel(iXi,iYi)!=0) {

                Toast.makeText(Mainact2.this, "menu",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true; 
            } 
            else {
                      // do work if transparent area

view2.bringToFront();

/*view2.requestFocus();
                        view2.requestFocusFromTouch();
                        view2.onTouchEvent(event);
*/


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What code do you have in `// do work if transparent area` part?

Comment: pplz chck..i have edited...

Comment: What triggers a `click` event is not the color of a `View` directly... Only way I could think of would be to detect if the clicked pixel was transparent or not and pass the event to the `View` behind... which ain't easy.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
 getWindow().addFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
```

Comment: Thanks, now I can pass touches to underlying view!

Answer (score 0):

If you can detect that the touch was on a transparent part, then return false from the OnTouchListener. That should pass the touch event down to the next view in that area.

Answer (score 0):

When you detect that the transparent area has been touched (which should trigger touch of the button below), then just call its touch/click handler.

Simplified code:

```
void btn1OnTouch()
{
    if (!transparent)
    {
        btn1Handler();
    }
    else
    {
        btn2Handler();
    }
}

void btn2OnTouch()
{
    btn2Handler();
}

void btn1Handler()
{
    //real job is done here
}

void btn2Handler()
{
    //real job is done here
}
```

Have you tried it this way?

Comment: Could you explain what exactly does not work or what is left to be done?

Comment: i have in one of stack-overflow's question .that if we have touch-listener on 2 buttons than being in one touch-listener we cannot call touch  listener of other button... .

Comment: i am unable to direct call to behind button ...on the click of transparent area of upper button

Comment: What is the problem to be unable to call? Do you get an error?

Comment: unable to call behind button ontouch